# Call load balancer from private subnet lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-elb

I have a internet-facing load balancer in a public subnet and have a privated hosted zone with a cname record for the load balancer as described [here](https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/containers/how-to-use-multiple-load-balancer-target-group-support-for-amazon-ecs-to-access-internal-and-external-service-endpoint-using-the-same-dns-name/). I try to request the record from a lambda in a private subnet which times out. I thought it is VPC internal and should resolve. Is that possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I try to request the record from a lambda in a private subnet which times out. I thought it is VPC internal and should resolve. Is that possible at all?

If you create cname in private hosted zone to the public DNS of your internet-facing load balancer, the traffic will **go over the internet anyway**. To use private traffic, you need **internal** load balancer, not public one.

Thus for your lambda function to access the ALB, you need to use **NAT gateway** to enable it accessing the internet.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question is about accessing a public load balancer from the Lambda function, not the other way around.

Comment: @MarkB Modified the answer.